# How to make one Div stick on Top of Another

Tags: javascript, css, html, positioning, css-position

I am building  a Poker Game .
[image]

I have made the card divs at the Footer draggable , so that they can be put on the divs numbered 1-13 .

[image]

But when I resize the window the card doesn't stick to the div . What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  //ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
  ui.draggable.position({

  my : 'left top',
  at: "left top",
  of: $(this)
});


}
```

2) Also how do I make the card resize and fit inside any of the divs numbered 1-13 ?

Comment: Are you using window resize javascript? Because if you use it, you will have to refresh the page on browser scale to make that fit.

Comment: yes, I am using a window resize javascript . You mean a literal fullpage refresh to be called ?

Comment: If you put some cards and resize your window, the issue will occur as you have mentioned. But when you refresh your browser in the same resized window, the issue will be solved, but will again occur on resize. Is this happening with you?

Comment: Well I am positioning the cards via manual drag drop . So I would lose the positions if I refresh .

Comment: Perhaps this is a job for Canvas. Floating divs is a hacky mess. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/